# Reading text file with NSString:stringWithContentsOfFile?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

Reading text file with NSString:stringWithContentsOfFile?

```
NSString *txtFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"\help" ofType:@"txt"];
NSString *txtFileContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:txtFilePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];

NSLog(@"File:  %@",txtFileContents);
```

I get "null" as the result.  How do I know what path to specify?

thanks

(I placed the file just under "Groups and Files" ... so not sure if I need to specify a path or just the file name.  Maybe there is something else wrong ???

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think the backslash in your path is confusing things.  Try this:

```
NSString *txtFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"/help" ofType:@"txt"];
```

Also, as noted in the comments, you need to use the Build Phase of your project to copy the "help.txt" file.

Comment: I think there are two things missing here: **1.** The path for the resource should be `@"/help"`, without the "txt" extension. **2.** You should copy the file in the **build phase**. Go to `Targets -> Build Phases` click + to add the "help.txt" file. Hope it helps. I had the same problem and I solved this way.

Comment: I think you've missed this small thing. In **Build phases** under **Compile Sources** you have to add the "help.txt" file.

Answer (score 5):

Try this. What you want is the path to `help.txt` but you have to split it up into its name and extension for the method to work.

```
NSString *txtFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"help" ofType: @"txt"];
```

It also wouldn't hurt to specify `NULL` instead of `nil` for the error argument. This is because `nil` represents objects whereas `NULL` represents pointers.

Comment: Tried... I still get"null" for the response... I added some more info up top!  thans

Comment: This worked as well after I changed a couple other things... so here I gave you a [point]... thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here's a common file that I include in a ton of my projects (.h first, followed by .m):

I name this one FileHelpers.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

NSString *pathInDocumentDirectory(NSString *fileName);
```

I name this one (of course) FileHelpers.m:

```
#include "FileHelpers.h"

NSString *pathInDocumentDirectory(NSString *fileName)
{
    // Get list of document directories in sandbox
    NSArray *documentDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    // Get one and only one document directory from that list
    NSString *documentDirectory = [documentDirectories objectAtIndex:0];

    // Append passed in file name to that directory, return it
    return [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

} // pathInDocumentDirectory
```

As an aside, I have to admit that I didn't come up with this solution myself, but it's been so long that I've used it that I can't remember now where I got it. If anyone knows, please feel free to attribute the appropriate credit!