# How to separate a String/CSV into 4 separate arrays

Tags: objective-c, arrays, csv, file-io

Ok so to start off I'm a beginner to objective c. I got a project where I'm suppose to take a csv file and read it into the system into 4 separate arrays, (City, Country, Latitude, and Longitude. My first question is can you use the old school `string` instead of `NNString`. I did the same project in c++ and this is what I got.

```
ifstream file("worldcities.csv");
getline(file, temporay);
//inputs the file into 4 arrays for each catergories
for (i=0;getline(file,(cities[i]),',');i++)
{
    getline(file, countries[i], ',');
    getline(file, latitude[i], ',') ;
    getline(file, longitude[i]);
}
```

How can I get the same outcome in Objective c? I tried `fgets` instead of `getline` but I'm still not familiar with it so thats why I came to you guys.

Comment: Just use [CHCSVParser](https://github.com/davedelong/CHCSVParser). No need to write your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have the cvs in a NSString object, try with this:

```
NSArray *array = [myString componentsSeparatedByString:@","]
```

This will give you a NSString object for every ',' separation.

If you have several lines, you will need to separate first between lines with this:

```
NSArray *lines = [myString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"]
```

Comment: but i want to use the c style array instead of nsarray

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6673267/reading-text-file-with-nsstringstringwithcontentsoffile

Comment: ok... then how do you separate the NNstring into 4 separate c arrays. Sorry for all the questions...like i said, i'm new to objective c